# How to change windows 10 “task view” Virtual Desktop Keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop, tasks

As you know, when we use <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left / Right</kbd> it'll change Virtual Desktops in windows 10 but I want to change (or add) to a new keyboard shortcut to change virtual desktops in Windows 10.
I need other keyboard shortcut instead of <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left / Right</kbd>

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear; please edit to clarify.

Comment: i think this is clear ! if you use "Windows Key + Ctrl + Left / Right" you can change from one desktop to another one , i need other keyboard shortcut instead of "Windows Key + Ctrl + Left / Right"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the shortcut keys for the build-in Virtual Desktop system in windows. If you want to use different hotkeys, you will be required to use other Virtual Desktop software that allows this, such as Dexpot or VirtuaDesk.

Comment: Maybe i can use additional hotkey instead of it . i am waiting to get new answers from another people

Comment: @radolf it was the first thing I wanted to do when I learned about Microsoft's Implementation of the Virtual Desktop. I was very disappointed when I did lots of research only to find out that it is very very limited, and up till today, it never changed, so eventually I went to a different Virtual Desktop software package. No way to change or add hotkeys, unless you go unconventional ways, like a script that fires another hotkey, which won't work all that great.